# Bootstrap experts - Input textfields do not work on pop up Modals

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using an open source Bootstrap landing page which features pop-up modals. In addition to that, I am using a third-party authentication software, which can be embedded on any page.

Now, when I embed this login form on any of the modals, the input textfields do not work, nothing is being typed in. However, if I was to embed the login form normally on the page, they do work.

Can anyone assist me why input fields do not work on the pop up modals, any how can I solve it?

The login form is embedded here: link-removed , Portfolio > Threads

Comment: why are you putting scripts inside the modal? i don't know the software you're using but scripts are placed in the end of the `body` tag and make sure you're placing scripts in the correct order.

Comment: I know they shouldn't be there- I will eventually take take it out I am just focusing on solving the issue- which I did, I removed tabindex="-1" from the Modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved by removing "tabindex="-1" from the Modal.